# Do I need to own the object in order to access it in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do I need to own the object in order to access it in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

Please get an overview by studying eg. [Access Control in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control.html).

In general you (or the `ROLE` you are using) do not need to *own* the object you want to access.  You/your `ROLE` needs to be granted access by the owner.

Access depends on the object type, for some objects you need to be granted the `USAGE` privilege, for DML operations you need to be granted `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.

Privileges are in general granted to a `ROLE`, so you need your `USER` to effectively use the `ROLE` that gives access to the object you want.

Comment: I would also add that if you want to ALTER an object's properties, you will need ownership to do that.  The link provided in this answer is great to get an overview.